# Difference between default and read-only 2nd-level Hiberate cache

Tags: hibernate, grails, caching

My Grails app has the following domain class

```
class Role {

    String authority

    static mapping = {
        cache usage:'read-only'
    }

    static constraints = {
        authority blank: false, unique: true
    }
}
```

Instances of this class are generally retrieved via a query such as

```
Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER', [cache: true])
```

Notice that the result of this query is cached (in Hibernate's 2nd-level cache) and for object's of type `Role` this cache has been declared read-only.

If the read-only cache definition shown above was replaced by a read-write cache i.e.

```
static mapping = {
    cache true
}
```

what difference would this make? My guess is that it when a read-only cache is used, any attempt at persisting a modification to an object retrieved from the cache causes an error Is this correct?

### Aside

In order for the query cache to be enabled, you also need to configure the following in `DataSource.groovy`

```
hibernate.cache.use_query_cache = true
```